# Monitor Azure Files in Storage Account for event : file creation

Tags: powershell, azure

I know I could use System.IO.FileSystemWatcher in a Powershell script to detect when a file is created in Azure files (in my storage account). Is there a better way to detect a file being created than this method ?
I can't seem to find any logs that I could perhaps parse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could do you if you really didn't want to use the `FileSystemWatch`

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -file -Recurse "C:\Temp"
$IfOlderThan = 60
$NewlyCreated = @()
$OldCreated = @()
$Count = 0

Foreach ($file in $files){
    if($file.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$IfOlderThan)){
        $NewlyCreated += $file
    } Else {
        $OldCreated += $file
    }
}
Write-Host "Found " -NoNewline;Write-host $($NewlyCreated.Count) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host " file\s that have been created in the last $IfOlderThan minutes" 
$NewlyCreated | select Name, Fullname, CreationTime
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very neat solution. It appears to be quite difficult to actually do something within Azure to find out what new files have been created.

Comment: I added the old created but didn't do anything with them. Put it there so you can decide what you want to do if there have been no new files created.